# Options to submit forms without frontend page requests

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I've been trying to find out as much as possible about the best way to submit forms without page requets meaning the forms are auto uploaded to database without the page reloading. In this case I'd like to know performance wise.

*NOTE: there are many posts on Stackoverflow that answer this question, though not specifically what I've asked.*

There only three ways I know are with JavaScript, AJAX and jQuery.
Example of both below.

JavaScript :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        submit_form();
});

function submit_form () {
    $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
    });
}
```

AJAX :

```
            $.ajax
                ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "file.php",
                data: ,
                cache: ,
                success: function (html)
                    {
                        alert("Order Submitted");
                    }
                });
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myform').submit(function()
{
    $('#myform').ajaxForm();
    return false;
});
```

Are there any better ways to accomplish this? 
If so, including JavaScript,AJAX and jQuery as I mentioned above, which is better? And which are faster?

Answer (score 1):

I am using this Js AJAX form submit function, becouse he is very universal:

```
function submitForm(form_id, response_id, url, callback)
{
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if (!url)
            url = window.location.href;


        var form_data = $('#'+form_id).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(msg) 
            {
                $("#"+response_id).html(msg);

                if(callback)
                    callback();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Just create in your page empty div, like submit:

```
  ...
  Your page content..
  <div id="submit"></div>
</body>
```

And when you need submit your form in same page:

```
submitForm('form_id', 'submit');
```

In other page:

```
submitForm('form_id', 'submit', 'My page url');
```

And if you need js callback in same page:

```
submitForm('form_id', 'submit', false, function(){ doSemethingAfterSubmit(); });
```

Or in other page

```
submitForm('form_id', 'submit', 'My page url', function(){ doSemethingAfterSubmit(); });
```

*And your PHP file can output js code, whick can warn user for errors and etc...*

Comment: How do I load this inside a class if there aren't any variables inside the (), I'm getting this error.. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) .

Comment: This is a great function, thank you for showing it as it's very useful to my project. Thank you for that. But now the issue.

I'm loading this inside a class, so I'm using public function and when I try to load userSubmit I get the error above on the public function submitForm(form_id, response_id, url, callback) line.

Comment: Copy error please. P. S. Why you add this function to js class?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '&' or variable (T_VARIABLE) in C:\EasyPHP-13.1VC11\data\localweb\public_html\includes\Wall_Updates.php on line 331 - line 331 is the function line. Even if I take it out and load it somewhere it gives me the same error. Sorry for the trouble.
It's not a JS class, I'm storing all my functions in a single document to not keep everything spread out, keep it more organized.

Comment: You stored js function in php class?

Comment: Oh gosh, nevermind that's my fault -_- I feel so dumb -_- thank you for the help, this will be helpful

Comment: Rate my answer if can, need reputation :)

Comment: I'm a bit confused how to load the submitForm('form_id', 'submit');, could you give a better example on the post if possible? I will definitely use this, it seems great.

Comment: <form id="myform"> inputs...... <input type="button" onclick="submitForm ('myform', 'submit'); </form>

Comment: Input type must be button, not submit!

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then because it's still not loading. Either way I don't want to bother you anymore, thank you for the help I will try and figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use **Ajax**

```
 $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: file.php,
            data: $("#form_id").serialize(), // form.serialize takes all the values of your input elements 
            success: function(data) {
                $('#message').html(data); // Here is a success message you can replace it according to your desire.
            }
        } );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1** uses a page submit
**Methods 1 and 2** use ajax

To prevent the page from changing/redirecting on a form submit you would need to use *ajax*, when communication is done over it the page is not affected, you can optionally provide a callback function which will deal with the data sent back by the server.

-Relfor

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on your api, I mean where you are submitting your data, in many places you will find you might have to integrate your code with someone's backend code.
it always best to pass info that backend demands like if you have to create a crazy component like drawing canvas or something, and save its state in backend, its impossible to do it in any way mentioned above. Unless you are creating  element to store canvas state.
So in my opinion using JS Object is best as you can send what is required my backend and nothing else.

```
$.ajax( {
  type: 'POST',
  url: file.php,
  data: {'key':'value'},// key should be exactly same as backend API demands it.
              // value should be in exactly same formate as API demands it.                           success: function(data) {
            $('#message').html(data); // Here is a success message you can replace it according to your desire.
        }
    } );
}
```

Comment: sorry for unformatted code, I just have changed data: part of ajax code nothing else.